# PHP and MySQL - use HAVING on count or no HAVING and array_filter?

Tags: php, mysql, aggregate-functions

I'd like to ask if there is a good practise about performance of following.

My SQL SELECT:

```
  SELECT avpc.category_id, a.attribute_id, ad.name, a.type, a.sort_order, avpc.attribute_value_id, avd.value, COUNT(pav.product_id) AS product_count
    FROM attribute_value_per_category  avpc
    JOIN category_path                 cp    ON cp.category_id = avpc.category_id
    JOIN attribute_value               av    ON av.attribute_value_id = avpc.attribute_value_id
    JOIN attribute_value_description   avd   ON avd.attribute_value_id = av.attribute_value_id AND avd.language_id = 2
    JOIN attribute                     a     ON a.attribute_id = av.attribute_id
    JOIN attribute_description         ad    ON ad.attribute_id = a.attribute_id AND ad.language_id = 2
    JOIN product_attribute_value       pav   ON pav.attribute_value_id = av.attribute_value_id
   WHERE path_id = 2
GROUP BY attribute_value_id
```

I need to add condition: `HAVING product_count > 10`. I've read, that HAVING is very slow and there is no optimisation in.

So I've got these two suggestions:

- Use HAVING
- Not use HAVING and filter out the condition in PHP (For example by array_filter)

Would you please to give me any advice of performance of this problem?

Comment: Questions about performance always require SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables as well as the result of the EXPLAIN

Comment: Yeah, I understand, but let's suppose that SQL query is optimized, well indexed and other relevant stuff. I'm asking only if there is a clear answer when MySQL HAVING is faster/slower than PHP filtering?

Comment: Well, the specific case of `> 0` doesn't require HAVING at all, as it can be answered with a join, so the question is in a sense irrelevant

Comment: Rather than trying to find some rule, I'd just suck it and see.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. If you don't want to answer, or don't know it, just don't write it. In the other way, answer the question, please.

Comment: @Honza - how many rows are returned, how may are product_count  < 10 ,...., so if your query returns 100000000 row and only 1 has product_count  < 10, then PHP is faster

Comment: There are dozens (hundreds max) of rows and the most of them are meeting the condition. So HAVING is faster in this case? If it's right, then move your comment as an answer to check it as correct. And if it's possible to add more detailed explanation, could you do it, please? Thank you.